# PHP. как проверить работает ли сайт, если сайт работает, но Connection timed out?

Tags: php

есть домашний сервер с DDNS, он работает извне, все ОК.
Есть сайт на хостинге на PHP, и ему необходимо проверять работает ли сервер.

Почитал, поискал и наткнулся на 2 решения проверки работы сервера - это сокеты или скачать любой файл с сервера. Это просто и понятно.

В итоге ни один из них не работает с DDnS. Я не могу разобраться почему.
Если я указываю вместо URL прямой ip (без домена ddns) то он тоже не работает

Используя **file_get_contents("*http://*".$ip.":".$port."*/WorkPage.aspx*");** - выдает **failed to open stream: Connection timed out**, причем указываю ip и порт напрямую без домена ddns.
Используя **fsockopen** или **cURL** - одно и то же.

Тут же ввожу этот же адрес в браузер - все работает. (опечатки проверил). 
Открываю сайт из другой сети - все работает.

Ошибка со стороны хостинга? Как с этим бороться и в какую сторону копать?

Comment: так может на том сервере с инетом напутано? вы попробуйте на нем из консоли wget'ом сделать запрос - если пройдет, тогда надо дальше php копать, а если не пройдет ни на сайт, ни на гугл, тогда надо будет в настройках сервера копаться.

Comment: @BOPOH, сервер рабочий, с ним точно проблем нет. Доступ к друг другу через консоль есть. А вот через PHP нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему не самым эстетичным путем:

на хостинге сделал 2 php файла  - один хранит текущий ip, и потом этот файл будет перезаписываться при загрузке сервера, который при смене своего ip заменит ip в этом файле.

2й файл делает проверку: на 2ip.ru у меня все таки проходила правильно проверка на вкл/выкл сервер, api нет, следовательно я просто качал страницу с проверкой ip и затем парсил результат.

Если у кого-то будет предложение как сделать лучше - я буду благодарен

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте через `curl`, например:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://".$ip.":".$port."/WorkPage.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
$data = curl_exec($ch);   
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: уже пробовал через curl - не работает.
Даже ваш код не сработал

Answer (score 0):

Ну надо понять что значит "работает" ли или нет и с помощью чего проверять.
Например, можно просто telnet'ом периодически открывать 80/443/какие_то_Ваши_порты и по ответу определять работу. Можно написать простой скрипт на bash/sh, например, с использованием wget:

```
#!/bin/sh

wget --output-document=/tmp/2.html -q --no-check-certificate --tries=3  --connect-timeout=4 --spider http://$1:$2
ret=$?
if [ "$ret" == 0 ]
then
    exit 0;
else
    exit 1;
fi
```

Скрипту передавать dns/ddns/ip port например script.sh moy_site.ru 80
Ну или прям ссылку можно, на Ваше усмотрение.

Comment: к сожалению на хостинге нельзя использовать консоль для выполнения скриптов, поэтому этот вариант отпадает